# Screen Capture multiple websites using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, screenshot, screen-scraping

Hi I need to download or (if not possible) take screen shots of multiple webpages which has images rendered using javascript(slick slides). using the phantomjs code for screen capture given in the website im able to take screen shot of a single web site. but im not able to manipulate the code to capture screenshots from multiple websites at once.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
eg site: http://www.flipkart.com/womens-clothing?otracker=nmenu_sub_women_0_All%20Clothing    need to capture banners from the site

Comment: What have you tired so far? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };
page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 1024, height: 768 };
page.open('http://example1.com/', function() {
  page.render('exampl1.png');
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };
page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 1024, height: 768 };
page.open('http://example2.com/', function() {
  page.render('exampl2.png');
phantom.exit();
});``
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? It looks like it achieves what you want. If it is not an answer to your question, then put this code into your question. You can edit your posts, so please move the code into your question and delete this "answer". Also, when you do, please describe in detail in what way this is insufficient (how it currently behaves and how you want it to behave). *The edit and delete buttons are right underneath your posts.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use IRobotSoft web scraper to do it.  Just let it go to different websites and call function CapturePage(filename) to capture the page into an image file.